# Итерация массивов в Cudafy

Tags: c#, cuda, nvidia

Есть код на *C#*, и мне его надо переделать, чтобы всё считалось на видео-карте:

```
public static double[] SATL(double[] data)
{
    double[] matrix = { 0.0982862174, ..., -0.0229204861, ..., 0.0161380976 };
    int dataLength = data.Length;
    int matrixLength = matrix.Length;
    int start = matrixLength + 1;
    var newData = new double[dataLength];

    if (dataLength <= matrixLength)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for (int i = matrixLength; i < dataLength; i++)
    {
        int counter = i - matrixLength;
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixLength; j++)
        {
            newData[i] += matrix[j] * data[counter++];
        }
    }

    return newData;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я пока не могу понять, как бегать по второму массиву. Не понимаю, как происходит индексация в *Cudafy*. Вот, что у меня получилось, но оно работает не правильно:

```
public static double[] FATLCuda(double[] data, double[] matrix)
    {
        CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
        GPGPU gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
        gpu.LoadModule(km);
        ...
        gpu.Launch().add(dev_data, dev_matrix, dev_newdata);                            
    }


[Cudafy]
public static void add(GThread thread, double[] data, double[] matrix, double[] newdata)
{
    int tid = thread.blockIdx.x;
    if (tid < data.Length)
    {
        int jid = 0;
        int counter = tid - matrix.Length;
        if (jid < matrix.Length)
        {
            newdata[tid] += matrix[jid] * data[counter++];
            jid++;
        }
        tid++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что бы быстрее получить ответ, попробуйте формализовать проблему. Конечно награда стимулирует отвечающих, но: не каждый будет разбираться в коде на C#; другой человек, столкнувшийся с проблемой не сможет найти ее поиском.

Comment: Ничего не понятно :| Какой "второй массив"? matrix? Что значит: "не получается бегать"? Перебрать в цикле?

Answer (score 1):

Не так давно в .net добавили поддержку [SIMD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD). Данное пространство имен позволяет использовать аппаратное ускорение. Для использования необходимо иметь [RyuJIT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/01/10453200.aspx) компилятор, .NET 4.6 и System.Numerics.Vectors, который ставится через Nuget.

Пример простейшей программы с использованием этого пространства имен:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const Int32 N = 8;
        Single[] a = { 41982.0F, 81.5091F, 3.14F, 42.666F, 54776.45F, 342.4556F, 6756.2344F, 4563.789F };
        Single[] b = { 85989.111F, 156.5091F, 3.14F, 42.666F, 1006.45F, 9999.4546F, 0.2344F, 7893.789F };
        Single[] c = new Single[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i += Vector<Single>.Count) // Count возвращает 16 для char, 4 для float, 2 для      double и т.п.
        {
            var aSimd = new Vector<Single>(a, i); // создать экземпляр со смещением i
            var bSimd = new Vector<Single>(b, i);
            Vector<Single> cSimd = aSimd + bSimd; // или так Vector<Single> c_simd = Vector.Add(b_simd, a_simd);
            cSimd.CopyTo(c, i); //копировать в массив со смещением
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Другими словами, используя это пространство имен, вы можете сделать все куда проще и красивее.